# Prototype of class's instances?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I'm trying to understand why the following code works the way it does.

I think it's contradictory that logging `killerRabbit.prototype` gives `undefined` while at the same time it seems to be equal to `Rabbit.prototype`.

Does it has an associated prototype but no actual prototype as a property?.

In that case, how do I access those prototypes properties?

```
class Rabbit {
  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  speak(line) {
    console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}'`);
  }
}
let killerRabbit = new Rabbit("killer");
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(killerRabbit)==Rabbit.prototype);//true
console.log(killerRabbit.prototype);//undefined
```

Comment: The prototype of an instance is not the value of its property "prototype".

Comment: Please read the description of tags when you add them to your question. `prototypejs` is an old library that was similar to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the prototype property on an instance, try this:

```
console.log(killerRabbit.__proto__);
```

And this property point to the `prototype` property of the based class.

```
console.log(killerRabbit.__proto__ === Rabbit.prototype); // true
```

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated. The `Object.getPrototypeOf` the OP shows in the question is the propper way to do it.